# Android Button Material Design With Image

Tags: android, button, material-design, android-imagebutton

I now use [MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary)

I want to use with the image

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
                android:id="@+id/buttonflat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#1E88E5"
                android:text="Button" />
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_restore"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:background="@color/default_btn_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/restore"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/default_btn_color"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_restore_download"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconTint="@color/dark_grey"
        tools:text="@string/restore" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
            android:id="@+id/buttonflat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#1E88E5"
            android:background-image="src=<src>"
            android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloat
                    android:id="@+id/buttonFloat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                    android:background="#1E88E5"
                    materialdesign:animate="true"
                    materialdesign:iconDrawable="@drawable/pencil" />
```

last line use to get an image from drawable folder..
or you can easily background attribute first make selector then

```
android:background="@drawable/mbtnselector"
```

and add xml name space

```
 xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

If you set the Drawable Icon by code in java it's like that:

```
buttonFloat = (com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloat)findViewById(R.id.buttonFloat);
if (buttonFloat != null) {
    buttonFloat.setDrawableIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_new));
}
```

Comment: OP said `ButtonFlat` not `ButtonFloat`

Comment: @EugenPechanec it is ButtonFloat not ButtonFlat
see
https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Comment: Open that exact link and examine the table of contents.

Comment: @Attaullah Khan, Nothing happens

Comment: it work fine for me @СергейСветлов. check your code, their may be have a mistake friend.

Comment: @Attaullah Khan, I use **flat**, not **floAt**

Comment: simply make a selector then 
try 
android:background="@drawable/mbtnSelector"